# Cannot change Primefaces p:commandButton font properties

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I need some customized buttons on my site which look differently than the others.
I've created a css class for these buttons but it behaves strangely.

this is the class:

```
.regCommandButton { 
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #29b6a0;
    border-color: #23a38f;

    width: 100%; 
    height: 25px; 

    font-family: 'pluto_sansthin';
    font-size:1.4em;    
}
```

font import in the same css file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'pluto_sansthin';
src: url(#{resource['fonts/plutosansthin-webfont.eot']});
src: url(#{resource['fonts/plutosansthin-webfont.eot?#iefix']}) format('embedded-opentype'),
     url(#{resource['fonts/plutosansthin-webfont.woff']}) format('woff'),
     url(#{resource['fonts/plutosansthin-webfont.ttf']}) format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

html implementation:

```
<p:outputPanel>
  <p:commandButton styleClass="regCommandButton" value="Save" action="#{URBean.saveNewUser}" update="regPanel" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

My problem is that the font related properties (font-family, font-size) are not being set if the button is inside of an `p:outputpanel` . All the others applies on the button.

If I put the button outside of the outputpanel, everything goes as expected.

**EDIT:**
Using !important for the font properties doesn't help eather.

Comment: Have your read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997)?

Comment: @mrganser:
Yes, I did and I load my stylesheet accordingly. In any other case I can override PF style classes. But in case of the button's font it just doesn't work.

Comment: `font-color` should be `color`

Comment: nice finding. it actually solved the color issue. unfortunatelly I still cant modify the size of the font and the font type.

Comment: And do you have that `pluto_sansthin` font imported as @font-face or something?

Comment: Yes, I do. I just updated the comment with the font import.

Comment: Replace `.regCommandButton` class to `.ui-button .regCommandButton`. And if it don't work try to inspect the button (i'm using chrome to do that) and you will see a `span` `css`class of `p:commandButton` text, try that too.

Comment: @Cold: It did the trick! Except that I had to remove the space which is between the two class name. So, the correct class definition is `.ui-button.regCommandButton{...}` and the correct html implementation remains `<p:commandButton styleClass="regCommandButton"/>`
Please post it as an answer and I accept it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this replacing `.regCommandButton` with `.ui-button.regCommandButton`.

Doing that you telling taht every element with `.ui-button` AND `.regCommandButton` will have the described proprieties:

```
.ui-button.regCommandButton { 
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #29b6a0;
    border-color: #23a38f;

    width: 100%; 
    height: 25px; 

    font-family: 'pluto_sansthin';
    font-size:1.4em;    
}
```